# Not Recognized Data Members in Specialized Structs/Classes

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, template-specialization, assignment-operator

For inclusion of conditional data members, I use specialized templates instead of namespaces, then overload assignment operator in each specialization. What happens is during compilation, member variables of specializations are not recognized. I do not understand why, and couldn't find anything on internet either.

```
enum Def : int {A, B};

template<Def T>
struct X {};

// Forward declaration does not help, like it would in non-template implementations. 
/*
*     template<>
*     struct X<B>;
*/

template<>
struct X<A>
{
    int a;
    int b;
    X<A> & operator = (const X<B> & obj)
    {
         a = obj.a;
         b = obj.b;
    }
}

template<>
struct X<B>
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    X<B> & operator = (const X<A> & obj)
    {
         a = obj.a;
         b = obj.b;
    }
}
```

Now what happens is, when compiling, I get the error that `X<B>` has no member named `a` and `b`. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, when `X<B>` is instantiated inside the definition of the specialization `X<A>`, (which is required by by the definition of `X<A>::operator =`,) the definition of specialization `X<B>` is not visible yet. That means it'll be [implicitly instantiated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Implicit_instantiation) from the primary template, which doesn't have member `a` and `b`.

You can move the definiton of `X<A>::operator =` out of the definition of specialization `X<A>` and after the definition of specialization of `X<B>`. e.g.

```
template<>
class X<A>
{
    int a;
    int b;
    X<A> & operator = (const X<B> & obj);
};

template<>
class X<B>
{
    ...
};

X<A> & X<A>::operator = (const X<B> & obj)
{
     a = obj.a;
     b = obj.b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains it very well.